# Where to define the Object to Broadcast in Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a database object which is used to insert data from all Spark executors. When I define this object as `static`, it has a `null` value in those executors. So I declare it in the driver, broadcast it then get its value in each executor. When  I run the application, the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: database.Database
```

Notes:

- The executors class is Serializable
- The broadcast object is defined as transient in that class
- I removed the transient but it didn't work

Comment: database object means? DTO or something else?

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and rewrite your question accordingly.

Comment: I created a class that handles connecting to database and all the database interactions.

Comment: You cannot serialize DB connections. It is yelling rightly `java.io.NotSerializableException`

Comment: Good. That's why I'm using broadcast, to share this object among all executors. Given that I got this exception, does this mean that broadcasted variable should be serializable?

Comment: Sure it should be. How can you broadcast without serializing? :)

Comment: I see :(... so how can I share that database object among all executors?

Comment: Either create connections(a pool of course) from all of them or post your data from executors to some intermediate service(some API or queue etc) and handle all DB calls from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your question this way:

> I want to insert data from my RDD from all Spark executors. I tried to create one DB connection on the Driver and pass it somehow as a Broadcast to the executors, but Spark keeps throwing `NotSerializableException`. How can I achieve my goal?

The short answer is:

> You should create a new connection on every executor node separately.
>   You should not pass database connection handlers, file handlers and the likes to other processes and especially remote machines.

The problem here is where exactly to create database connections, because with large number of executors one can easily exceed connection pool size of the DB.

What you can actually do is to use [foreachPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#foreachPartition(scala.Function1)), like here:

```
  // numPartitions == number of simultaneous DB connections you can afford
  yourRdd.repartition(numPartitions)
  .foreachPartition {
    iter =>
      val connection = createConnection()
      while (iter.hasNext) {
        connection.execute("INSERT ...")
      }
      connection.commit()
  }
```

Here the code inside `.foreachPartition` will be executed on each executor machine, and connection objects will not be sent over the network, you won't have serialization exceptions and the data will be inserted.

The same reasoning about use of `foreachPartition` is also mentioned in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484701/spark-foreach-vs-foreachpartitions) question.