# Apache Spark - Iterators and Memory consumption

Tags: apache-spark

I am a newbie to the spark and have question regarding spark memory usage with iterators.

When using Foreach() or MapPartitions() of Datasets (or even a direct call to iterator() function of RDD), does spark needs to load the entire partition to RAM first (assuming partition is in disk) or can data be lazy loaded as we continue to  iterate (meaning that spark can load only part of the partition data execute task and save to disk the intermediate result)

Answer (score 0):

The first difference of those two is that `forEach()` is an action when `mapPartition()` is a transformation. It would be more meaningful to compare `forEach` with `forEachPartition` since they are both actions and they both work on the final-accumulated data on the driver. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484701/apache-spark-foreach-vs-foreachpartitions-when-to-use-what) for a detailed discussions over those two. As for the memory consumption it really depends on how much data you return to the driver. As a *rule of thumb* remember to return the results on the driver using methods like `limit(), take(), first()` etc and avoid using `collect()` unless you are sure that the data can fit on driver's memory.

The `mapPartition` can be compared with the `map` or `flatMap` functions and they will modify the dataset's data by applying some transformation. mapPartition is more efficient since it will execute the given func fewer times when map will do the same of each item in the dataset. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185092/apache-spark-map-vs-mappartitions) for more details about these two functions.