# Best practice writing JavaRDD to external DB

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JavaRDD that I need to persist to some external DB.

What would be the best way to do it so I don't suffocate my DB with enormous number of connections? That is - I would like to have control over the number of Connection pools created in my Spark app.

I believe that `rdd.forEach` would be a bad option as it might create a connection pool for each row. I assume that `rdd.foreachPartition` is probably better but not quite sure.

Comment: Perhaps you can convert it to dataframe df, `df.repartition(x)` to x=number of connections your DB can tolerate, and then save using Spark JDBC datasource `jdbcDF.write
  .format("jdbc").option(...).save()`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html `foreachPartition()` would also work but... why?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I can't use JDBC with my database...

Comment: rdd.foreachPartition is better than rdd.foreach

Comment: _I can't use JDBC_ - then its probably not about Best practice. Will this post help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484701/apache-spark-foreach-vs-foreachpartitions-when-to-use-what