# How to save one row from DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have a problem with writing row by row to output from DataFrame. I write my own solution, but it's too slow, so maybe there is a builtin solution for this problem.

The goal is to write dataframe's rows separately to the output.
My code:

```
window = Window.partitionBy(col1).orderBy(col2)
df = df.withColumn("nb", f.row_number().over(window))

for i in range(df.count()):
   (df
    .where(f"nb = {i+1}")
    .drop("nb")
    .select(f.to_json(f.struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])).alias("value"))
    .write
    .format("console")
    .save())
```

Is it possible to make this faster?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It's slow because you're using a loop. If you want an index, that's not the way to do it. Plus, you're dropping the column, so what's the purpose of the nb column or having each one be a separate DF that's printed?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yeah, I know it's because of the loop. I need to send rows from dataframe (telemetry data) to other system. Thats is why I need to send them one by one (system requires that). So how I achive that with spark utuilities?

Comment: @Łukasz To confirm, do you needs to send them one at a time or you are sending to an API that accepts only one data item at a time?

Comment: @Nithish, yes I need to send only one row at a time, API accetps only one row at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with an API that can accept only one row item at a time.
You can use [`foreach`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach.html?highlight=foreach#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreach) or [`foreachPartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.foreachPartition.html?highlight=foreachpartition#pyspark.RDD.foreachPartition). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191864) provides a great overview of the differences between them.

> You can also repartition the dataframe to control the number of parallel connections established.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

data = [("James","","Smith","36636","M",3000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",4000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","M",4000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",4000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",-1)
  ]
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("firstname", "middlename", "lastname", "id", "gender", "salary", ))


def mimic_send_to_api(iterator):
    # mimic intitiate costly session with API
    session = print
    for item in iterator:
        session(f"sent to API: {item.value}")

df.select(f.to_json(f.struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])).alias("value"))\
  .foreachPartition(mimic_send_to_api)
```

### Output

```
sent to API: {"firstname":"James","middlename":"","lastname":"Smith","id":"36636","gender":"M","salary":3000}
sent to API: {"firstname":"Michael","middlename":"Rose","lastname":"","id":"40288","gender":"M","salary":4000}
sent to API: {"firstname":"Robert","middlename":"","lastname":"Williams","id":"42114","gender":"M","salary":4000}
sent to API: {"firstname":"Maria","middlename":"Anne","lastname":"Jones","id":"39192","gender":"F","salary":4000}
sent to API: {"firstname":"Jen","middlename":"Mary","lastname":"Brown","id":"","gender":"F","salary":-1}
```